# How to stop OneDrive from autostarting

Tags: macos, mojave

When I boot up my Mac there is a OneDrive icon in the menu bar. If I select it I see a dialog asking me to configure it. I can quit the application, but how do stop it from restarting again?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t need it uninstall it.

If you still need it then check in System Preferences for your account and remove it from the login items.

Comment: It does not appear under login items.

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the file

`~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.OneDriveMigrationLauncher.plist`

finally stopped it from auto-launching at boot/login

Mac OS : Mojave